# Should I normalise my database in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I got stuck with one problem in my website's database. I hope that I explained it well enough below:

My website's idea is to show prices in different shops for the same product. For example I have product "shoesA" it is sold in shopA, shopB, and shopC.

The prices for shoesA are as follows:

```
shopA : 107$,
shopB : 114$,
shopC : 97$
```

I can see 2 major ways of storing data about the product:

**1)** Store ALL the data regarding a single product in a single table, in a single row. This will require using 2D arrays.

Example:

```
ID=48,
Name="shoesA",
Brand="brandA",

Prices="[["shopA" , 107] , [["shopB " , 114] , [["shopC " , 97]]",
```

**2)** Divide this all into separate tables.

Example:

`table_product_info`

```
ID=48,
Name="shoesA",
Brand="brandA"
```

`table_product_prices_shopA`

```
ID=4,
Product_ID=48,
Price=107
```

`table_product_prices_shopB`:

```
ID=4,
Product_ID=48,
Price=114
```

`table_product_prices_shopC`

```
ID=4,
Product_ID=48,
Price=97
```

Why do I think that 1 is faster, hence, better than 2:

To get the entire data for shoesA using method 1 I only need to perform 1 query. But for method 2 it will possibly be 10 queries.

Thank you very much if you spent your time reading this and trying to help!

Comment: Products table (id, name, brand). Shops table (id, name). Prices table (id, product_id, shop_id, price).

Comment: You have a third way, to have a product table, a shop table and a price_product_shop table, that maybe the best option

Answer (score 2):

both are not quite right.

you want the product table to list the product details.
then you want the store table to list the store details.

then finally you need one to tell which product is sold by which store something like this:

```
store_product
______________
store_id
product_id
begin_date
end_date
price
```

Comment: Thank's for the idea. But will a normalized database as the one you suggested take a significantly longer time to be queried from over a database with only 1 table? Or is this only a question of flexibility?

(significant for me is > 25%)

Thank's again!

Comment: no this is what database engines are great at. you will have nightmares if you try your design #1.

Comment: @AndreiMikhov - The speed depends on the query more than the schema.  Show us the queries; we can then compare schemas.  Meanwhile, I like Randy's approach, which is similar to those suggested by Akina and nacho.